# How to change scroll speed in Midnight Commander?

Tags: mc

Single click mouse turn seems to be equivalent to PageUp/PageDown in Midnight Commander. I don't like this as I expect scrolling to be more smooth - every time I scroll a portion of the items previously displayed is to go and a portion is to remain, it doesn't feel like scrolling when the whole screen content is replaced and no elements of the previous display are kept. How do I adjust this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck Options/Panel options: Mouse page scrolling